# Why does this js submodule pattern return the original module and not the augmented module?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this interesting [javascript patterns post](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html), the blog author returns the parameter passed in (`parent`) as opposed to `my` which works if the reference modified already exists, but if the modules which are loading in parallel hasn't been created yet, the new object `{}` will be augmented and the new module never gets created. Is this a bug? I doubt it since no one in all the years has mentioned it. What don't I understand.

```
var UTIL = (function (parent, $) {
    var my = parent.ajax = parent.ajax || {};

    my.get = function (url, params, callback) {
        // ok, so I'm cheating a bit :)
        return $.getJSON(url, params, callback);
    };

    // etc...

    return parent;
}(UTIL || {}, jQuery))
```

Comment: Probably the other module has the same structure

Comment: @Jonas W. Ok, so that there are shared privates. I don't think that's what the author was doing in the context of the blog because he does that differently.

Comment: @JonasW. Before this pattern he does that under the heading Cross-File Private State in a slighltly different way and then describes this as way for augmentation.

Comment: @JonasW. Actually, I think that must be the answer.

Comment: *but if the modules which are loading in parallel hasn't been created yet, the new object {} will be augmented and the new module never gets created* it gets created?!

Comment: @JonasW. On the global scope UTIL it never gets created as a property. It just gets used privately and then discarded unless a partial module definition elsewhere creates it.

Comment: It gets created. Run the script and you can do `UTIL.ajax.get()`

Comment: @JonasW. Indeed it does. I wasn't thinking about the parent and ``my`` referencing the same new object in the equals chain. Thanks!

Comment: @user5389726598465 `my` does not reference the same object as `parent`. But `parent` references the same object as `UTIL`.

Comment: @Bergi The following doesn't make them reference the same object? ``var my = parent.ajax = parent.ajax || {};``

Comment: No. That makes `my` reference the same object as `parent.ajax`.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that's right. Ajax and my are now references. Thanks. But it still makes sense to me. You can't confuse me anymore now!